# Process a list of IO intensive tasks in parallel with RxJava

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, observable, rx-java

I need to get some files in parallel. The get operation itself is IO intensive, and can benefit greatly from parallel execution.

With RxJava I was able to achieve this by wrapping my function with `Async.toAsync`.

I was wondering if there would be a cleaner way with using [subscribeOn()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#subscribeOn(rx.Scheduler)), or [observeOn()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#observeOn(rx.Scheduler))? I wasn't able to figure it out. Tried different ways, but only one thread would be used any way, and the processing happened sequentially.

```java
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Scheduler;
import rx.functions.Func1;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
import rx.util.async.Async;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ParallelMultiGet {

    public List<String> readContents(List<String> paths) {

        Func1<String, String> getFunction = new Func1<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(String path) {
                return get(path);
            }
        };

        Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(
                Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
                        Math.min(paths.size(), 50)));

        Future<List<String>> result = Observable
                .from(paths)
                .flatMap(
                        Async.toAsync(getFunction, scheduler))
                .toList()
                .toBlocking()
                .toFuture();
        try {
            return result.get(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // For example if Func1.call above throws an exception it ends up in here
            throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't read paths", e);
        }
    }

    private String get(String path) {
        // this would be the slow operation, waiting for IO
        return "content";
    }

}
```

Even this is quite nice already, because I don't need to build my own loops that submit futures and combine values from them to the result list. But maybe it wouldn't have to be this verbose?

Comment: You don't need async for that; just a plain `ExecutorService` has `.invokeAll()`

Comment: That's worth mentioning here indeed. The result is a List<Future>, so still need to at least iterate that and map the values into a list. The overall complexity is lower with `invokeAll()`, but this question is primarily about how this could be done with RxJava. It would be nice to find a convenient way with method chaining, and also to be able to use the `Observable.from` etc. instead of iterating the `paths` "manually" to create the tasks for `invokeAll()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be less verbose :

- you can use timeout operator from RxJava
- you can use java8 with lambda instead of Func1 (but won't help much in your case)
- you can avoid to create your own executor

I got this code that should be doing the same thing of yours :

```
  public List<String> readContents(List<String> paths) {

      try {

        return Observable
                .from(paths)
                .flatMap(Async.toAsync((Func1<String, String>) this::get, Schedulers.io()))
                .toList()
                .timeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .toBlocking().single();
      } catch (RuntimeException ex) { // the cause will be a timeoutException
        // For example if Func1.call above throws an exception it ends up in here
        throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't read paths", ex);
      }
    }

    private String get(String path) {
        // this would be the slow operation, waiting for IO
        return "content";
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there. `Async.toAsync` still seems kinda clumsy to me but if that's how this is done with RxJava, fine.The problem with `Schedulers.io()` is that it will create an infinite number of threads. On the other hand `Schedulers.computation()` restricts to 4 threads (or this might depend on the number of cores). That's another issue really, and it would be rather simple to extend `Schedulers` to have something like `Schedulers.fixed(int size)` or even better `Schedulers.cached(int maxSize)`.

Comment: `.timeout()` + `.single()` is just beautiful. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You can use the overloaded flatMap() which takes the max number of concurrently subscribed observables as a second parameter.